# CakePHP Blank Foreign Key

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a situation where a user is asked to fill out a questionnaire about a building. The `Building` model *could* `hasMany Questionnaire` though, at least for now, it's sufficient that the `Building hasOne Questionnaire`. What's bothering me is that the former doesn't work while the latter does and I can't figure out why.

The keys follow convention: `buildings.id` is referenced in a foreign key from `questionnaires.building_id`. In the `hasMany` scenario, the foreign key just gets ignored when attempting to insert the `questionnaires` record:

```
INSERT INTO `questionnaires` (`deleted`, `modified`, `created`, `id`) VALUES (1, '2011-03-17 10:32:24', '2011-03-17 10:32:24', '4d821b78-7314-4ab4-a532-226f6e891b5e')
```

No mention of the `building_id` at all. As soon as I move `Questionnaire` from the `hasMany` array to the `hasOne` array, though, it all works perfectly.

Any insight into the inner magic would be great. I can't imagine that I'm the first person to bump into this, but I don't ever remember running into it before.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So I think I found the answer. In my form, since I'm really only defining *one* questionnaire (although I could support multiple), I was defining my input as `Questionnaire.deleted` which works fine for `hasOne`, but not so much for `hasMany`. For the latter, I have to create the input for `Questionnaire.0.deleted`. I've created forms for countless `hasMany` relationships where I was only intended to create one at a time and I swear I can't remember ever having to do that before. Has that always been a requirement? Maybe I just need to put down the hard stuff for a while. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Wilkerson,

[this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data#!/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo) could mean that it always has been a requirement. I guess the reason for bumping into this issue is a mixture of hand-written and generated (`cake bake`) code, which occurs naturally.

So if one does not change the requirements during development and starts out with the generated code, it is possible to never look closely at the `hasMany` related `0s` and everything stays fine.

Imho the framework could remove this source of error by handling `hasOne` as a subset of `hasMany` when it comes to forms. This way updating views could be omitted when relationships have to be changed.

Maybe filing an issue for the cake devs is indicated?